# numpy multiply matrices preserve third axis

Tags: python, numpy

if I have `k` many `n,m` matrices represented by a `n,m,k` numpy array, how can I multiply that by `k` many `m,j` matrices represented by a 'm,j,k' numpy array at the same time giving me a `n,j,k` ndarray?

In other words, I need to perform `k` many matrix multiplications of `n,m * m,j = n,j`. Is it possible to perform them at once?

EDIT: All of the dimensions vary, but are in general large.

Comment: If you could show the sizes of each dimension it could help quite a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second solution of @Ophion can do without a loop, and it is faster with larger dimension:

```
In [65]:

#k,n,m,j=2,4,5,6
k,n,m,j=100,101,102,103
A=np.random.random((n,m,k))
B=np.random.random((m,j,k))
In [66]:

%timeit np.rollaxis(np.array(map(np.dot, np.rollaxis(A,2), np.rollaxis(B,2))), 0, 3)
1 loops, best of 3: 313 ms per loop
In [67]:

%timeit np.einsum('nmk,mjk->njk',A,B)
1 loops, best of 3: 793 ms per loop
```

And slower than `enisum` when dimension is small:

```
In [68]:

k,n,m,j=2,4,5,6
#k,n,m,j=100,101,102,103
A=np.random.random((n,m,k))
B=np.random.random((m,j,k))
In [69]:

%timeit np.rollaxis(np.array(map(np.dot, np.rollaxis(A,2), np.rollaxis(B,2))), 0, 3)
10000 loops, best of 3: 73.7 µs per loop
In [70]:

%timeit np.einsum('nmk,mjk->njk',A,B)
100000 loops, best of 3: 13.5 µs per loop
```

Sure, this is for `python 2.x`, in `3.x`, be aware that the `map` returns `map object`s.

Comment: Two things: First the roll axises is an interesting idea; however if you run the python loop solution it is actually faster then your roll axis solution. Second the memory layout is what makes these operations so slow, if you change the arrays around so that `k` is the first axis all operations are much faster making the above solution slower due to the memory manipulations required.

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on the size and shape of your arrays. Where `n`,`m`, and `j` are small you can do something like the following:

```
import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.rand(5,2,1E6)
>>> b = np.random.rand(2,5,1E6)
>>> out = np.einsum('nmk,mjk->njk',a,b)
>>> out.shape
(5, 5, 1000000)
```

If `n`, `m`, and `j` are large you might want to take advantage of a BLAS like so:

```
>>> a= np.random.rand(1E3,1E2,5)
>>> b= np.random.rand(1E2,1E3,5)
>>> out = np.empty((1E3,1E3,5))
>>> for x in range(out.shape[-1]):
...     out[:,:,x] = np.dot(a[:,:,x], b[:,:,x])
```

Keep in mind that numpy arrays are row-major. You may want to rearrange your data depending on what you are doing.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I was trying to see if there was a way to avoid the for loop

Comment: @user79950 The `einsum` answer has no explicit for loop. I am not sure what you were expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Using Daniels code Python 3.10 complains TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer. This can be fixed casting 1E6 to integer with `a = np.random.rand(5,2,int(1E6))`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).