# Python Numpy matrix multiplication in high dimension

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, machine-learning, linear-algebra

I am trying to look for a matrix operation in `numpy` that would speed up the following calculation.

I have two 3D matrices `A` and `B`. the first dimension indicates the example, and both of them have `n_examples` examples. What I want to achieve is to dot product each example in A and B and sum the result:

```
import numpy as np

n_examples = 10
A = np.random.randn(n_examples, 20,30)
B = np.random.randn(n_examples, 30,5)
sum = np.zeros([20,5])
for i in range(len(A)):
  sum += np.dot(A[i],B[i])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a typical application for `np.tensordot()`:

```
sum = np.tensordot(A, B, [[0,2],[0,1]])
```

---

**Timing**

Using the following code:

```
import numpy as np

n_examples = 100
A = np.random.randn(n_examples, 20,30)
B = np.random.randn(n_examples, 30,5)

def sol1():
    sum = np.zeros([20,5])
    for i in range(len(A)):
      sum += np.dot(A[i],B[i])
    return sum

def sol2():
    return np.array(map(np.dot, A,B)).sum(0)

def sol3():
    return np.einsum('nmk,nkj->mj',A,B)

def sol4():
    return np.tensordot(A, B, [[2,0],[1,0]])

def sol5():
    return np.tensordot(A, B, [[0,2],[0,1]])
```

Results:

```
timeit sol1()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.46 ms per loop

timeit sol2()
100 loops, best of 3: 4.22 ms per loop

timeit sol3()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.87 ms per loop

timeit sol4()
10000 loops, best of 3: 205 µs per loop

timeit sol5()
10000 loops, best of 3: 172 µs per loop
```

on my computer the `tensordot()` was the fastest solution and changing the order that the axes are evaluated did not change the results neither the performance.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! It does produce the fastest solution on my computer as well!. However, if you increase the matrix size (from `20x30`, `30x5` to around `600x300`,`300x10`) then `sol1()` becomes fastest again and is 5x faster than the `tensordot` solution. I wonder why looping in python would be faster than native C implementation such as `tensordot`

Comment: @aha, that's a surprise for me too, I would expect the `tensordot()` to be faster. Did you also compare `sol4()` and `sol5()`, changing the order in which the axes are evaluated? Perhaps this can make a difference...

Comment: using matrix size of `600x300`,`300x10`, `sol1()` takes `16.5ms`, `sol4()` takes `113ms` and `sol5()` takes `89ms`

Answer (score 2):

Ha, it can be done in just one line: `np.einsum('nmk,nkj->mj',A,B)`.

See Einstein summation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html

Not the same problem but the idea is quite much the same, see discussions and alternative methods in this topic we just discussed: [numpy multiply matrices preserve third axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23574806/numpy-multiply-matrices-preserve-third-axis)

Don't name your variable `sum`, you override the build-in `sum`.

As @Jaime pointed out, the loop is actually faster for dimensions of these size. In fact a solution based on `map` and `sum` is, albeit simpler, even slower:

```
In [19]:

%%timeit
SUM = np.zeros([20,5])
for i in range(len(A)):
  SUM += np.dot(A[i],B[i])
10000 loops, best of 3: 115 µs per loop
In [20]:

%timeit np.array(map(np.dot, A,B)).sum(0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 445 µs per loop
In [21]:

%timeit np.einsum('nmk,nkj->mj',A,B)
1000 loops, best of 3: 259 µs per loop
```

Thing are different with larger dimension:

```
n_examples = 1000
A = np.random.randn(n_examples, 20,1000)
B = np.random.randn(n_examples, 1000,5)
```

And:

```
In [46]:

%%timeit
SUM = np.zeros([20,5])
for i in range(len(A)):
  SUM += np.dot(A[i],B[i])
1 loops, best of 3: 191 ms per loop
In [47]:

%timeit np.array(map(np.dot, A,B)).sum(0)
1 loops, best of 3: 164 ms per loop
In [48]:

%timeit np.einsum('nmk,nkj->mj',A,B)
1 loops, best of 3: 451 ms per loop
```

Comment: It is 50% slower than the OP's code for his problem size, and much worse for really large inputs.

Comment: A slightly faster method for larger dimension, not impressively better. `einsum` becomes even slower. Must sleep now and hope to be enlightened by solutions from the west-coast. :P

Comment: is it slower than the tensordot?

Comment: Do you happen to know if any other languages' library would provide a more optimized solution?

Comment: I would suggest you timeit your code, just make sure it is indeed slower for the calculation you are doing.  See related discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365073/why-is-numpys-einsum-faster-than-numpys-built-in-functions.

Comment: Also the `numpy` version is written in `C` https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/src/multiarray/einsum.c.src, you might ask the author for suggestions as well.